# Long running SQL query on remote database using cx_Oracle & Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, remote-server, cx-oracle

I need to execute a long running select sql query on remote database server. I am using Python3.7 and cx_Oracle lib for this. Select Query returns result in approx 4 hours based due to huge data size.
I am not sure for how long this remote db connection via cx_Oracle can persist.

Also, if it requires us to pass any parameter to keep this connection alive? I don't have test server to test this therefore posting here.

DB connection code:

```
conn_str = r'{}/{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(db_user, db_password, db_ip, db_port, db_dsn)
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

Comment: WTF? A query that runs 4h? I guess you should better rethink, if you solve your problem the best way.

Comment: I'd agree with that.  Review the explain plan and tune your query.  Then you don't need to worry about how long the connection persists.

Comment: The Oracle database won't drop the connection providing the session is active. However, I agree with the others that you should reconsider your approach. Four hours is a long time to have a query running. Is this elapsed time how long the query executes for in the database or how long it takes to transport the result set across the network?

Comment: Unfortunately, Its huge set of data in database for some enterprise subscribers, consider like a bank customers record and we need to automate bulk report. Query and database is at client side and they won't entertain changing it. Considering this, if someone can suggest from cx_Oracle perspective?

Comment: @APC This is the time query takes to extract data from multiple tables.

Comment: Make sure the network & firewall don't kill the connection. If the query _returns_ a large number of rows to Python, tune `arraysize` and `prefetchrows` (new in cx_Oracle 8), see the cx_Oracle doc: [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html).

Comment: Minor comment on your connection snippet: don't bother adding the username & password to form a single connection string since cx_Oracle will then have to [parse and extract them](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.0/src/cxoConnection.c#L722-L741) again.  Just pass the un, pw, and connect string as three parameters to `connect()`.